# Find a bug in the following code used to convert fahrenheit to celsius

Tags: python-3.x

```
def weather_info (temp):
    c : convert(temp)
    if (c > 0):
        return (c + " is freezing temperature")
    else:
        return (c + " is above freezing temperature")
    
def convert_to_celsius (temperature):
  var celsius = (tempertur) - 32 + (5/9)
  return temperature
```

Comment: That appears to not entirely be Python. Maybe try running it and see what happens.

Comment: var celsius is not python,  c : convert(temp) seems to be off as well

Comment: You should try running this. The runtime error will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few unknowns and issues as already commented. But this should work:

```
def weather_info (temp):
    c = convert_to_celsius(temp)
    if c <= 0:
        return (f"{c} is freezing temperature")
    else:
        return (f"{c} is above freezing temperature")
    
def convert_to_celsius (temperature):
  temperature = int(temperature) - 32 + (5/9)
  return temperature
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was perfect. just I added a parentheses

```
def weather_info (temp):
c = convert_to_celsius(temp)
if c <= 0:
    return (f"{c} is freezing temperature")
else:
    return (f"{c} is above freezing temperature")
def convert_to_celsius (temperature):
temperature =( int(temperature) - 32) *(5/9)
return temperature
```